# Why is my paint bubbling and peeling after removing my popcorn ceiling?

Tags: paint, repainting

I removed my popcorn ceiling.  I made all my repairs, and wiped the ceiling down after I sanded the entire ceiling.

I was trying to prime the ceiling but my paint is bubbling and peeling. What should I do?

Comment: How old is your home ? 1920's 1930's etc?

Comment: What kind of paint are you using?

Comment: Did you use Dulux paint? We had our house painted using Dulux and every wall now has hundreds of bubbles and blisters. I have now been on a number of sites and have found many comments about problems with Dulux paint bubbling. It seem both interior and exterior Dulux paint have this problem. No one seems to know why the paint is bubbling. Further, no help from Dulux.